# XAMPP MySQL Database doesn't start in Mac OSX Yosimite Beta 2

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

Today, I update Yosimite Beta 2 and I can't start MYSQL Database (Apache + ProFTPD are OK).

This is report:

```
Process:               ??? [9308]
Path:                  /Applications/XAMPP/*/mysqld
Identifier:            ???
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [Unknown]
User ID:               0

Date/Time:             2014-08-23 14:48:38.900 +0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A329r)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        DB229915-180C-ADA1-2E8C-4BF39B0A0016


Time Awake Since Boot: 2300 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Error Formulating Crash Report:
Failed to read dyld_all_image_infos: Coudln't get the data

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x7fff644b7075 dyld_fatal_error + 1
1   dyld                            0x7fff644bbd77 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3122
2   dyld                            0x7fff644b7276 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512
3   dyld                            0x7fff644b7036 _dyld_start + 54
```

Please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit file: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp

and before

`$XAMPP_ROOT/bin/mysql.server start > /dev/null &`

paste it:

`unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start it quickly, open your terminal and run following command:

> sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start

This will start MySQL instantly.